# Azure NotificationHubClient throws SocketException when used on Azure function intensively

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub, azure-hub

We are using an Azure function to send push notifications via Azure NotificationHubClient. This function is called a lot at peak times on live environment and as a result we got a lot of SocketExceptions thrown from the NotificationHubClient.SendNotificationAsync() method.

Exception details:

```
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.MessagingException: Unexpected exception encountered TimeStamp:2020-03-27T04:14:35.4655705Z ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String trackingId, HttpStatusCode[] successfulResponseStatuses, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.ExceptionsUtility.HandleUnexpectedException(Exception ex, String trackingId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.ExceptionsUtility.TranslateToMessagingException(Exception ex, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, String trackingId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String trackingId, HttpStatusCode[] successfulResponseStatuses, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendNotificationImplAsync(Notification notification, String tagExpression, String deviceHandle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

We create the NotificationHubClient like:

`new NotificationHubClient(connectionString, hubName, new NotificationHubClientSettings
 {
    OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
 });`

I've observed that the Microsoft implementation behind is instantiating a new HttpClient on each new NotificationHubClient instantiation - which would probably be the problem(the well known socket exhaustion), but I have no ideea how this could be tackled.

Has anyone confronted with the same problem and managed to fix it some way? Thanks

Comment: Hey there, @vtrenea. Would you mind opening a support ticket through the Azure portal? The engineering team would like to investigate your situation further.

Comment: we are having very similar issues, however our exception is quite different. 'Unable to connect to the remote server.TrackingId:92cf019d-f3fc-4721-ac99-4e375f65f68b,TimeStamp:2020-04-08T06:56:24.9336294Z'  but it is related to high volumes of pushes being sent,  when we reboot the app, it immediately starts working again.

Answer (score 4):

In the end we managed to overcome the problem by injecting

```
    IHttpMessageHandlerFactory _httpMessageHandlerFactory;
```

in our class and pass it to the notificationHubClient in the constructor:

```
    return new NotificationHubClient(connectionString, hubName, 
    new NotificationHubClientSettings
    {
       OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
       MessageHandler = _httpMessageHandlerFactory.CreateHandler()
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did this? We cannot get this working?  We running in a windows service and want to use the same instance of 'httpclient'

Answer (score 0):

There is a RESTful API for Notification Hubs. You can see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/rest-api-methods). If you wanted more control, you could write your own wrapper around the methods you need, making sure to set the HttpClient instance as a static member variable within your Azure Function.

Comment: Could one not just use a singleton / static instance of your 'NotificationHubClient'.   Would this be safe to do? Have the authors of the library designed it in a way that I can be reused over and over.

Comment: Turns out you cannot. The Nuget library recreates the `HttpClient` object every time..